# Guard clause in Rails unless

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rubocop

I am using Rubocop in my rails application and it suggests Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression for this. Plz suggest a clean way to rewrite it.

```
    def exist
      @account = Account.find_by(id: params[:id])
      unless @account.present?
        render json: { error: 'Account is not available' }, status: :not_found
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

RuboCop is suggesting a change such as this:

```
    def exist
      @account = Account.find_by(id: params[:id])
      render json: { error: 'Account is not available' }, status: :not_found unless @account.present?
    end
```

But whether this is more 'clean' is subjective.